# How to turn off standard osx text editing bindings in emacs on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings

I want to not have any standard osx text editing bindings available in emacs anymore. I'm using standard gnu emacs. leaving only the "old school" emacs commands. In other words: no more command+c for copy, no  command+z for undo, etc. Is there some way to do this without explicitly rebinding each key combination? I tried googling for a way to do this but did not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These key bindings are defined [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/term/ns-win.el#L102), in `ns-win.el`.

There seems to be no simple way to unbind all of them.  You could copy all of those key bindings from `ns-win.el` into the scratch buffer.  They look like this:

```
(define-key global-map [?\s-,] 'customize)
```

Then hit `C-M-%` for `query-replace-regexp`, type `^(define-key global-map \(.*\) '.*)$` as the search expression and `(global-unset-key \1)` as the replacement, turning those key bindings into:

```
(global-unset-key [?\s-,])
```

Then, select them all and type `M-x eval-region`.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs in OS X, the default setup is that the CMD key is bound to the SUPER qualifier, and the a number of keys like S-x, S-c, and S-v are bound to commands to minic the normal OS functions. The OPTION key is bound to META. Unfortunately, the basic setup doesn't allow you to type characters that normally would require the OPTION key, like "|" and "\".

The following will bind CMD to meta and make OPTION available for normal character composition.

```
(if (boundp 'ns-command-modifier)
    (setq ns-command-modifier 'meta))

(if (boundp 'ns-option-modifier)
    (setq ns-option-modifier nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

The keybindings I find objectionable are the bindings to <kbd>SUPER</kbd> aka <kbd>command</kbd>. To disable these binding, though not all the `NS` bindings made:

File `global-unset-all-super-key.el`:

```
(defun global-unset-all-super-key ()
  "Will unset any single key in global keymap that has the super
modifier."
  (let ((km (current-global-map)))
    (while km
      (let ((maybe-event (and (listp (car km))
                              (caar km))))
        (if (and (eventp maybe-event) ; Also filters maybe-event when
                                      ; nil because (car km) was not a list.
                 (memq 'super (event-modifiers maybe-event)))
            (global-unset-key (vector maybe-event))))
      (setq km (cdr km)))))

(provide 'global-unset-all-super-key)
```

Place `global-unset-all-super-key.el` in the Emacs lisp load path and add the following to `init.el` or `.emacs`:

```
;; Remove default super bindings on Mac systems.
;; Do this early, before any mappings are added.
(when (string-equal system-type "darwin")
  (require 'global-unset-all-super-key)
  (global-unset-all-super-key))
```